# How can a component send a message to its sibling without moving the state up the component tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I've got a "page" component which houses a form and a list. The form and the list are completely self-contained and disjoint except for the fact that when you save the form, the list should refresh.

My page component looks like this, in its entirety:

```
export default class PaymentsPage extends React.PureComponent {

    static propTypes = {
        bookingId: XPropTypes.stringOrNumber.isRequired,
        test: PropTypes.bool,
        stripePublishableKey: PropTypes.string,
        stripeUserId: PropTypes.string,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ContentSection title="Enter Payment" storageKey="record-payment">
                    <RecordPaymentForm bookingId={this.props.bookingId} test={this.props.test} />
                </ContentSection>
                <ContentSection title="Previous Payments" storageKey="previous-payments">
                    <PreviousPaymentsTable bookingId={this.props.bookingId} test={this.props.test} stripePublishableKey={this.props.stripePublishableKey} stripeUserId={this.props.stripeUserId} />
                </ContentSection>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My question is, how can `RecordPaymentForm` send a message to `PreviousPaymentsTable` to tell it to refresh?

I don't want to move `RecordPaymentForm`'s state up into `PaymentsPage` because I want it to remain self-contained.

I'm not using flux/redux, nor do I plan on it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [mufa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mufa) (event oriented programming), communication among siblings will be as following :

#### Component Sender (Publisher) :

```
import {fire} from 'mufa';

class RecordPaymentForm extends React.Component {

     // Assuming that the trigger to send the message is the following
     handleClick() {
       const message = 'this is a message from RecordPaymentForm';
       fire('sendSomething', message); 
     }
}
```

#### Component Receiver (Subscriber) :

```
import {on} from 'mufa';

class PreviousPaymentsTable extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      on('sendSomething', (message) => {
         this.setState({recordPaymenetMessage: message});
      })
    }
}
```

```js
//if your are using npm => import {on, fire} from 'mufa';
const {on, fire} = window.mufa; 

class RecordPaymentForm extends React.Component {


     onClick(event) {
       fire('addPayment', this.refs.item.value, this.refs.price.value); 
     }
     
     render() {
       return (
          <div>
            <input ref="item" placeholder="item name" /> 
            <input ref="price" placeholder="price" type="number" />
            <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Add</button>
          </div>
          )
     }
}



class PreviousPaymentsTable extends React.Component {
  
    state={records:[]}
    componentDidMount() {
      on('addPayment', (item, price) => {
         this.setState({records: [...this.state.records, {item, price}]});
      })
    }

   
   render() {
    
      return (
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.records.map((r, index) => 
              <li key={index}> <b> {r.item} : </b> {r.price} $ </li>)
          }
        </ul>
      ) 
    }
}


class App extends React.Component {


  render() {
  
    return (
      <div>
         <RecordPaymentForm />
         <PreviousPaymentsTable />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('section'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/abdennour/mufa/ddf78fd9/cdn/mufa-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<section />
```

## General Rules for React with Event-driven :

1. `publish (fire)` : is called in events handlers.
2. `subscribe (on)` : is called in `componentDidMount`.
3. `unsubscribe (off)` : is called in `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: Looks a lot like the solution I came up with [PubSub-JS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS). Does mufa have any advantages over that?

Comment: 0. mufa **Babel**ified
1. support multiple-messages : if you call `fire('eventName', msg1 , msg2, msg3)` you will find those 3 messages in the callback of subscriber `on `: -> `on('eventName', (msg1, msg2, msg3) => )` . 

2. supports multiple-contexts: You can create another registry : `import Mufa from 'mufa'; const m1= new Mufa(); m2= new Mufa(); `... then no relationship between `m1.on` && `m2.fire`.. so you have two different contexts. 

3 . `mufa` uses aliases to make code more readable and pleasant : `on` is an alias of `sub`,`fire` is an alias of `pub`, `off` is an alias of `unsub`

Comment: Anyway, whatever the lib u will use, the common things  are to call `pub (fire)` in the event handlers ... and call `sub (on)` in `componentDidMount`. .. and call `unsub (off)` in `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to move RecordPaymentForm's state up into PaymentsPage because I want it to remain self-contained.

To your point above, `RecordPaymentForm` *isn't* self contained if you want it to update another component.

The proper "React" way to handle this situation is to store the shared state for both `RecordPaymentForm` and `PreviousPaymentsTable` in the parent component (`PaymentsPage`) and pass it into each child component.

To update the state of `PaymentsPage` from `RecordPaymentForm`, you can pass a function as a prop to act as a handler. and you can create the `handleChange` function in `PaymentsPage`.

```
export default class PaymentsPage extends React.PureComponent {

  static propTypes = {
    bookingId: XPropTypes.stringOrNumber.isRequired,
    test: PropTypes.bool,
    stripePublishableKey: PropTypes.string,
    stripeUserId: PropTypes.string,
  };

  handleChange(newValue) => {
    this.setState({
      someProp: newValue;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ContentSection title="Enter Payment" storageKey="record-payment">
          <RecordPaymentForm 
            bookingId={this.props.bookingId} 
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            someProp={this.props.someProp}
            test={this.props.test} 
          />
        </ContentSection>
        <ContentSection title="Previous Payments" storageKey="previous-payments">
          <PreviousPaymentsTable 
            bookingId={this.props.bookingId} 
            test={this.props.test} 
            someProp={this.props.someProp}
            stripePublishableKey={this.props.stripePublishableKey} 
            stripeUserId={this.props.stripeUserId} 
          />
        </ContentSection>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It's proper if they need to share state, but they don't really. I only need to know when *something* happened. I don't need any details at all from that event. Moving all the state up means I can't easily re-use my payment form anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented [PubSubJS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) in about 3 lines of code. I think it will work well for this particular use-case.

When a payment is entered, I publish a "paymentEntered" event. Any component that's interested (such as my `PreviousPaymentsTable`) can subscribe to that topic, and then do what it needs to.

More-over, I could even publish the payment data and pop it into my payments list so that I don't have to do a full refresh, but I'm going to anyway because I already have the code for it and I don't mind a 50ms delay for fresh data.

This way my payments page remains dumb, and I can move these components around to any page, and re-use them where ever I please, with or without each-other, and they'll continue to work.