# Share state in top level React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mufa

I need to use react in different parts of my page but share the same state so I made this on the top level:

```
ReactDOM.render( 
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

ReactDOM.render( 
    <Dragbar />,
    document.getElementById('offCanvas')
);
```

The main code is "App" but how do I send state to "Dragbar"? (I only need to send it not set). Is this where I need to start learning redux etc? I've just started learning React so haven't looked at other libraries yet. P

Comment: Wait, where are you keeping state react or redux ? Note that they both solve the same problem of maintaining state

Comment: react core not redux (yet)

Comment: or mobx, whatever you need some kind of data layer.. otherwise the shit flows only in one direction ;)

Comment: You can skip the Redux complexity and to share state globally by using Reactn https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactn  
Doing so you are up and running in minutes, handling global state the same as local state, with calls linr setGlobal()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

working with redux can help you share one state all over your app without thinking what data to pass and what not.
if you want to pass data to child without redux you can like that:

```
<Dragbar someData=[1,2,3] />
```

and in your component you can use this data `{this.props.someData}`

look at react docs or in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcCcZ1IWZ6w

Comment: Can redux let me pass to a separate unrelated (non child) component?

Comment: Yes, it will. You just pass the same instance of store

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to kick off with react without redux, you can do by sharing e.g. An Event Emitter or `Subject` from the rx library in order to pass events from ne component to the other. The idea is then to

1. create the event mediator
2. pass it to both components
3. register with the event mediator such that upon a new message/event you can call `setState` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use **Event Oriented Programming** (pub/sub) to make communication among components which have not the same parent .

[**mufa**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mufa) does the job of event-driven .

I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42059874/747579) with an exampe of MUFA and i will write below an example that meets exactly your requirements :

## General Rules for React with Event-driven :

1. `publish (fire)` : is called in events handlers.
2. `subscribe (on)` : is called in `componentDidMount`.
3. `unsubscribe (off)` : is called in `componentWillUnmount`

```js
const {on, fire} = mufa; 


class App extends React.Component {

  state={input:""};

  componentDidMount() {
    on('dragbar_change_state', (...args) => {
       this.setState(...args);
     })
  }
  
  setStateAndFire() {
   fire('app_change_state',...arguments);
   super.setState(...arguments);  
  } 
  
  render() {
     return (<div>Dragbar is saying : " {this.state.input} "</div>)
  }
    
} 

class Dragbar extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    on('app_change_state', (...args) => {
       this.setState(...args);
    })
  }
   
  setStateAndFire() {
    this.setState(...arguments);  
    fire('dragbar_change_state',...arguments);

  } 

   handleKeyUp(event) {
     this.setStateAndFire({input: event.target.value});
   }

    render() {
     return (<div><input type="text" onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp.bind(this)} placeholder="Write somthing here you will see it in App component" style={{fontSize:15, width: 400}} /></div>)
    } 
}



ReactDOM.render( 
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
ReactDOM.render( 
    <Dragbar />,
    document.getElementById('offcanvas')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/abdennour/mufa/ddf78fd9/cdn/mufa-latest.min.js"></script>
<h3>App Mounted in Root</h3>
<div id="root" ></div>
<hr />
<h3>DragBar mounted in offcanvas</h3>
<div id="offcanvas" ></div>
```

Comment: disclaimer, OP is the author of mufa

Comment:  .. another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42059874/747579) about the same topic of event-driven .. try to go there, and try to write the same comment

Comment: your answer is good, but you should disclose if you are the author of that library.

Comment: @DanPantry: alright ! is it a rule of stackoverflow ? if so , i wil do and i am grateful for this info . Anyway, i start building its tag [tag:mufa]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229085/how-to-offer-personal-open-source-libraries/229091#229091. Specifically, "Always disclose that it is your project. This avoids any accusations of astroturfing". To be clear, I'm trying to help you here rather than hound you :)

Comment: Alright! got it