# Retrieve the status from multiple axios requests called from multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a sort of Dashboard in my application. In this dashboard I let the user put many widgets (each widget is a class component). Each widget renders different stuff, such as, charts, images, and text. When I display it, each widget make an axios call to retrieve data from backend. I need a way to be able to tell when all the requests have finished so I can get the HTML completely rendered (I'm going to export it using HiqPdf later).

I need each widget to be independent so I can use in other components. That's why each widget make its own axios call. Otherwise I think I could make many axios calls in a single component that is above my widgets and then I would pass all the data as props to each widget. However, no... the axios calls must stay inside each widget.
I've found many places talking about promises, but every example talks show how to do it in a single component.

The reason I'm working on it is because I have the need to export it using a library call HiqPdf. This library receives a HTML as string and exports to PDF. Therefore, I need to know when the dashboard has been completely loaded to let the application export it.

Comment: When a User is creating a Dashboard is it real-time? As in, do you have an "edit Dashboard" view with a "save" button, or do you immediately perform requests as one-offs when a widget is added?

Comment: I have both cases. The user can edit or just display the dashboard. However, it's the same component. The difference is that in edit mode the user can put new widgets, or place them in other position. Therefore, in both cases I make the axios calls.

Answer (score 1):

Think about an event-driven framework that persists the **global state** of your single page app and notify subscribers whenever there is a change in the state.

One of the famous frameworks is [redux](/questions/tagged/redux).

Another simple framework is [mufa](/questions/tagged/mufa). These are some similar questions that leverages [mufa](/questions/tagged/mufa):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124013/747579
- [Stop the communication between react components using mufa after a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42771843/747579)

For your case, it might be something like this:

```
const all_calls = [];
const {on, one, fire, unsub} = mufa;

axios.get('call1').then((data) => {

   fire('call1_received', data);
})


axios.get('call2').then((data) => {

   fire('call2_received', data);
});


one('call1_received', () => {
  all_calls.push('call1_received');
  if (all_calls.length === 2) {
     alert('!!!! All calls have been received')
  }

})

one('call2_received', () => {
  all_calls.push('call2_received');
  if (all_calls.length === 2) {
     alert('!!!! All calls have been received')
  }

})
```

Note, [`one`](http://elegance.abdennoor.com/mufa/#one) will subscribe once only.. while `on` subscribe forever.

Comment: What if I don't know how many axios calls I'm going to have? Since in my dashboard the user can add as much widgets as he wants, I would need to count it before, right?

Comment: Please, see if this approach would be a good practice. What if I count the number of widgets I have in my dashboard, and store it in redux? That would be the first thing to do when I begin the export process. After storing it, I would procced and each widget would increment an int variable in redux after finishing its request. Finally, when the number of widgets is equal to the int variable, I enable the option to Export.

Comment: @ArthurMedeiros counting is not a good way to go about it unless you have a constructor that can manage the data. Imagine you have 5 promises, then you edit a widget while those promises haven't been resolved.Now you have 6 different async calls. Whichever finish first, even if incorrect, are going to propagate.